# cPickle ImportError: No module named multiarray

Tags: python, serialization, numpy, pickle

I'm using cPickle to save my Database into file. The code looks like that:

```
def Save_DataBase():
import cPickle
from scipy import *
from numpy import *
a=Results.VersionName
#filename='D:/results/'+a[a.find('/')+1:-a.find('/')-2]+Results.AssType[:3]+str(random.randint(0,100))+Results.Distribution+".lft"
filename='D:/results/pppp.lft'
plik=open(filename,'w')


DataOutput=[[[DataBase.Arrays.Nodes,DataBase.Arrays.Links,DataBase.Arrays.Turns,DataBase.Arrays.Connectors,DataBase.Arrays.Zones],
             [DataBase.Nodes.Data,DataBase.Links.Data,DataBase.Turns.Data,DataBase.OrigConnectors.Data,DataBase.DestConnectors.Data,DataBase.Zones.Data],
             [DataBase.Nodes.DictionaryPy2Vis,DataBase.Links.DictionaryPy2Vis,DataBase.Turns.DictionaryPy2Vis,DataBase.OrigConnectors.DictionaryPy2Vis,DataBase.DestConnectors.DictionaryPy2Vis,DataBase.Zones.DictionaryPy2Vis],
             [DataBase.Nodes.DictionaryVis2Py,DataBase.Links.DictionaryVis2Py,DataBase.Turns.DictionaryVis2Py,DataBase.OrigConnectors.DictionaryVis2Py,DataBase.DestConnectors.DictionaryVis2Py,DataBase.Zones.DictionaryVis2Py],
             [DataBase.Paths.List]],[Results.VersionName,Results.noZones,Results.noNodes,Results.noLinks,Results.noTurns,Results.noTrips,
                                     Results.Times.VersionLoad,Results.Times.GetData,Results.Times.GetCoords,Results.Times.CrossTheTime,Results.Times.Plot_Cylinder,
                                     Results.AssType,Results.AssParam,Results.tStart,Results.tEnd,Results.Distribution,Results.tVector]]



cPickle.dump(DataOutput, plik, protocol=0)
plik.close()`
```

And it works fine. Most of my Database rows are lists of a lists, vecor-like, or array-like data sets.

But now when I input data, an error occurs:

```
def Load_DataBase():
    import cPickle 
    from scipy import *
    from numpy import *  
    filename='D:/results/pppp.lft'
    plik= open(filename, 'rb')
    """ first cPickle load approach """
    A= cPickle.load(plik)
    """ fail """
    """ Another approach - data format exact as in Output step above , also fails"""
    [[[DataBase.Arrays.Nodes,DataBase.Arrays.Links,DataBase.Arrays.Turns,DataBase.Arrays.Connectors,DataBase.Arrays.Zones],
                 [DataBase.Nodes.Data,DataBase.Links.Data,DataBase.Turns.Data,DataBase.OrigConnectors.Data,DataBase.DestConnectors.Data,DataBase.Zones.Data],
                 [DataBase.Nodes.DictionaryPy2Vis,DataBase.Links.DictionaryPy2Vis,DataBase.Turns.DictionaryPy2Vis,DataBase.OrigConnectors.DictionaryPy2Vis,DataBase.DestConnectors.DictionaryPy2Vis,DataBase.Zones.DictionaryPy2Vis],
                 [DataBase.Nodes.DictionaryVis2Py,DataBase.Links.DictionaryVis2Py,DataBase.Turns.DictionaryVis2Py,DataBase.OrigConnectors.DictionaryVis2Py,DataBase.DestConnectors.DictionaryVis2Py,DataBase.Zones.DictionaryVis2Py],
                 [DataBase.Paths.List]],[Results.VersionName,Results.noZones,Results.noNodes,Results.noLinks,Results.noTurns,Results.noTrips,
                                         Results.Times.VersionLoad,Results.Times.GetData,Results.Times.GetCoords,Results.Times.CrossTheTime,Results.Times.Plot_Cylinder,
                                         Results.AssType,Results.AssParam,Results.tStart,Results.tEnd,Results.Distribution,Results.tVector]]= cPickle.load(plik)`
```

Error is (in both cases):

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\programy\projekt_eclipse\src\Praca\wx_frame.py", line 342, in LoadDatabase_Handler
    Load_DataBase()
  File "D:\programy\projekt_eclipse\src\Praca\wx_frame.py", line 1804, in Load_DataBase
    A= cPickle.load(plik)
ImportError: No module named multiarray
```

Any Ideas?

PS. Now I've solved the problem, say partially :/ I needed to change the format of arrays. I've tried to trace the error, but I couldn't. The variable causing error is this (long :) )  :

```
[[  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  1.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   0.00000000e+00]
 [  2.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   3.52875186e+04]
 [  3.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   2.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   2.24880978e+04]
 [  4.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   3.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   2.24880978e+04]
 [  5.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   4.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   2.24880978e+04]
 [  6.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   2.24880978e+04]
 [  7.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   6.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   2.24880978e+04]
 [  8.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   7.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   3.59846476e+04]
 [  9.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   8.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   0.00000000e+00]
 [  1.00000000e+01   1.00000000e+03   0.00000000e+00   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   3.97583022e+04]
 [  1.10000000e+01   1.00000000e+03   1.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   1.84929461e+04]
 [  1.20000000e+01   1.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   8.76891311e+03]
 [  1.30000000e+01   1.00000000e+03   3.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   5.10636164e+03]
 [  1.40000000e+01   1.00000000e+03   4.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   2.45841100e+03]
 [  1.50000000e+01   1.00000000e+03   5.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   4.22093915e+03]
 [  1.60000000e+01   1.00000000e+03   6.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   9.20282091e+03]
 [  1.70000000e+01   1.00000000e+03   7.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   1.86566159e+04]
 [  1.80000000e+01   1.00000000e+03   8.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   3.80902598e+04]
 [  1.90000000e+01   2.00000000e+03   0.00000000e+00   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   2.23193676e+04]
 [  2.00000000e+01   2.00000000e+03   1.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   1.16000116e+04]
 [  2.10000000e+01   2.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   9.05680012e+03]
 [  2.20000000e+01   2.00000000e+03   3.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   6.89123867e+03]
 [  2.30000000e+01   2.00000000e+03   4.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   4.98898168e+03]
 [  2.40000000e+01   2.00000000e+03   5.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   7.44216130e+03]
 [  2.50000000e+01   2.00000000e+03   6.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   1.23593332e+04]
 [  2.60000000e+01   2.00000000e+03   7.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   1.14424233e+04]
 [  2.70000000e+01   2.00000000e+03   8.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   1.91864355e+04]
 [  2.80000000e+01   3.00000000e+03   0.00000000e+00   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   2.07766798e+04]
 [  2.90000000e+01   3.00000000e+03   1.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   8.61849685e+03]
 [  3.00000000e+01   3.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   1.09785208e+04]
 [  3.10000000e+01   3.00000000e+03   3.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   8.99736773e+03]
 [  3.20000000e+01   3.00000000e+03   4.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   9.06209122e+03]
 [  3.30000000e+01   3.00000000e+03   5.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   9.48702707e+03]
 [  3.40000000e+01   3.00000000e+03   6.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   1.04653099e+04]
 [  3.50000000e+01   3.00000000e+03   7.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   6.25314801e+03]
 [  3.60000000e+01   3.00000000e+03   8.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   1.67608539e+04]
 [  3.70000000e+01   4.00000000e+03   0.00000000e+00   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   2.07766798e+04]
 [  3.80000000e+01   4.00000000e+03   1.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   6.82241178e+03]
 [  3.90000000e+01   4.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   8.05149043e+03]
 [  4.00000000e+01   4.00000000e+03   3.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   9.55692239e+03]
 [  4.10000000e+01   4.00000000e+03   4.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   1.19199226e+04]
 [  4.20000000e+01   4.00000000e+03   5.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   8.43876335e+03]
 [  4.30000000e+01   4.00000000e+03   6.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   4.90454231e+03]
 [  4.40000000e+01   4.00000000e+03   7.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   6.03525083e+03]
 [  4.50000000e+01   4.00000000e+03   8.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   1.67608539e+04]
 [  4.60000000e+01   5.00000000e+03   0.00000000e+00   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   2.07766798e+04]
 [  4.70000000e+01   5.00000000e+03   1.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   6.07842319e+03]
 [  4.80000000e+01   5.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   6.48191278e+03]
 [  4.90000000e+01   5.00000000e+03   3.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   1.06547361e+04]
 [  5.00000000e+01   5.00000000e+03   4.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   1.27500595e+04]
 [  5.10000000e+01   5.00000000e+03   5.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   9.62319628e+03]
 [  5.20000000e+01   5.00000000e+03   6.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   6.50364667e+03]
 [  5.30000000e+01   5.00000000e+03   7.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   6.48651846e+03]
 [  5.40000000e+01   5.00000000e+03   8.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   1.67608539e+04]
 [  5.50000000e+01   6.00000000e+03   0.00000000e+00   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   2.16862400e+04]
 [  5.60000000e+01   6.00000000e+03   1.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   9.88311307e+03]
 [  5.70000000e+01   6.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   7.89923519e+03]
 [  5.80000000e+01   6.00000000e+03   3.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   8.16959736e+03]
 [  5.90000000e+01   6.00000000e+03   4.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   6.49942081e+03]
 [  6.00000000e+01   6.00000000e+03   5.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   6.24620368e+03]
 [  6.10000000e+01   6.00000000e+03   6.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   9.27811830e+03]
 [  6.20000000e+01   6.00000000e+03   7.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   1.13336356e+04]
 [  6.30000000e+01   6.00000000e+03   8.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   1.91853045e+04]
 [  6.40000000e+01   7.00000000e+03   0.00000000e+00   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   3.67326624e+04]
 [  6.50000000e+01   7.00000000e+03   1.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   1.79192625e+04]
 [  6.60000000e+01   7.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   9.35835049e+03]
 [  6.70000000e+01   7.00000000e+03   3.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   4.66349011e+03]
 [  6.80000000e+01   7.00000000e+03   4.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   1.88664273e+03]
 [  6.90000000e+01   7.00000000e+03   5.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   4.15546726e+03]
 [  7.00000000e+01   7.00000000e+03   6.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   9.26420582e+03]
 [  7.10000000e+01   7.00000000e+03   7.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   1.80179725e+04]
 [  7.20000000e+01   7.00000000e+03   8.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   3.69846102e+04]
 [  7.30000000e+01   8.00000000e+03   0.00000000e+00   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   0.00000000e+00]
 [  7.40000000e+01   8.00000000e+03   1.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   3.66207833e+04]
 [  7.50000000e+01   8.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   2.32529854e+04]
 [  7.60000000e+01   8.00000000e+03   3.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   2.32529854e+04]
 [  7.70000000e+01   8.00000000e+03   4.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   2.32529854e+04]
 [  7.80000000e+01   8.00000000e+03   5.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   2.32529854e+04]
 [  7.90000000e+01   8.00000000e+03   6.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   2.32529854e+04]
 [  8.00000000e+01   8.00000000e+03   7.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   3.70098656e+04]
 [  8.10000000e+01   8.00000000e+03   8.00000000e+03   2.00000000e+01
    0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+02   2.00000000e+01   0.00000000e+00]]
```

cPickle, or pickle are unable to load it. But when I do it manually with the console, the same file structure ( [[ ]] and all formats exaclty the same, values also e+00 format) Then it works fine ??????????? What the hell?
Anyway I've solved the problem by changign data format :/

Comment: I'm betting you're using git?

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem on a Windows XP machine with Code that worked fine under Linux. It may have to do with the different handling of text and binary files. When writing your data try to create the file object explicitly stating that you want binary mode, i.e.

```
plik=open(filename,'wb')
```

instead of

```
plik=open(filename,'w')
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

First of all check if $YOUR_PYTHON_INSTALLATION/lib/python-x.x/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so file exists.

And it would be very useful if you posted full traceback, not only the error message.

Comment: I've checked it, it works fine, and the file exists,
from numpy.core import multiarray as multiarray
 I've also reinstalled numpy it doesn't help. I post full traceback into question

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried importing multiarray explicitly? pickle needs all the classes to be defined in order to import the data.

Comment: You mean: 
from numpy.core import multiarray as multiarray
nope - it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

This can be caused by git changing line endings on a Windows machine with autocrlf. You'll notice that it won't be a problem until you change branches or do anything else that deletes and rewrites the file on disk.
Add this line to your `.gitattributes` file to avoid rewriting line endings in the text-like (but actually binary!) pickle files:

```
# .gitattributes
# Pickle files are to be treated as binary. 
*.p binary
*.lft binary
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be using a very old Python. Because 'import *' is only available at module level. Anyway, to answer your question:

Move these statements

```
import cPickle 
from scipy import *
from numpy import *
```

out of the Load_DataBase definition and you'll be fine. The exception was raised because cPickle can't find the meta information for the content of plik.