# Serialize a Python method with global variables by dill

Tags: python, serialization, pickle, dill

Here's an example code where `FLAG` is a global variable. The method `A.func` is a blackbox to me so that I don't know it calls `FLAG` before serialization.

```
import dill as pickle
FLAG = 100

class A:
  def func(self):
    print FLAG * 10

a = A()
dump = pickle.dumps(a.func)
del FLAG
foo = pickle.loads(dump) <-- fail here "NameError: global name 'FLAG' is not defined"
foo()
```

In related questions:

- [Serialize a python function with dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26389981/serialize-a-python-function-with-dependencies)
- [How to pickle a python function with its dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048061/how-to-pickle-a-python-function-with-its-dependencies)

The most practical solution is using `cloudpickle`.  But it seems that `dill` is more robust than `cloudpickle`. So I'd like to stick to `dill` or other mature picklers.

I don't mind to modify some `dill` code by myself if necessary.

Thanks for any help in advance :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm the `dill` author.  It works if you use the `recurse` setting, which handles globals very similarly to how `cloudpickle` handles globals.

```
>>> import dill
>>> FLAG = 100
>>> 
>>> class A:
...   def func(self):
...     return FLAG*10
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> dump = dill.dumps(a.func, recurse=True)
>>> del FLAG
>>> foo = dill.loads(dump)
>>> foo()
1000
>>>
```

`dill` provides several settings, that give you serialization variants. If you want to always use this setting, then you can do this:

```
>>> dill.settings['recurse'] = True
```